# Converting Date from ZoneDateTime gives local times instead of ZonedTime

Tags: java, date, java-8, zoneddatetime

I am trying to convert the ZonedDateTime to a Date. Looks like in the conversion, it looses the time zone and gets my local time.

```
System.out.println("zoneDate1::::::::::"+ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")));
System.out.println("zoneDate1:Date::::::::::"+Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")).toInstant()));
```

The above outputs as below:

```
zoneDate1::::::::::2016-04-15T17:35:06.357-05:00[America/Chicago]
zoneDate1:Date::::::::::Fri Apr 15 18:35:06 EDT 2016
```

Is this because this is a Date type? How would i go about doing this kind of conversion and conserve the zoned time?

Comment: A `java.util.Date` (which I'm guessing you're using) doesn't have the notion of timezone. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Tunaki, thanks for editing, i was doing the same thing as you did it.

Comment: My database has a Date column which needs to be stored with date which is in different timezone than where the application is running from.

Comment: Should Date.from just convert the ZonedDateTime into Date instead of determining the value again?

Comment: Which DB are you using? For PostgreSQL you can use a "timestamp with time zone". A SQL Date doesn't hold a timezone either. If it's MySQL, you'll need to use 2 columns: 1 for the Date and 1 for the timezone (yes it's a pain).

Comment: Hmm.. shouldn't Date.from retrieve the date passed to it instead of redetermining the value in local timezone? As you guessed, I am using MySQL :(

Comment: Congrats, you just found out why those classes are broken :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109284/discussion-between-mandy-and-tunaki).

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem? What did you expect? I see no misbehavior.

Your java.time type (`ZonedDateTime`) is assigned a time zone of `America/Chicago`.

Your JVM apparently has an assigned time zone related to east coast of North America, the clue being the `EDT` value seen in string output. The `toString` method on java.util.Date applies your JVM’s current default time zone when generating its textual representation of the date-time value. Poorly designed, this behavior is trying to be helpful but is actually confusing because you cannot actually get or set this time zone on the java.util.Date object.

At any rate, the east coast of North America (such as `America/New_York` time zone) is an hour ahead of `America/Chicago`. So you are seeing `17:xx:xx` time for Chicago and `18:xx:xx` for [Eastern Daylight Saving Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/edt). These values are correct.

You should call `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()` when investigating the behavior of the old date-time classes.

## java.time

The bigger problem is that you are even using these old date-time classes such as java.util.Date/.Calendar. They are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid these old classes altogether. They have been supplanted in Java 8 and later by the java.time framework.

Also, avoid using 3-4 letter zone abbreviations like `EDT`. These are neither standardized nor unique. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in continent/region format.

### `Instant`

To capture the current date-time in java.time, just use [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). This class captures a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Do most of your work in UTC. No need for time zones unless expected by your user when displayed in the user interface.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

### Database

To send to your database, first make sure you have defined the column in the table as something along the line of the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. By the way, support for date-time types various among databases with some doing a much better job than others.

Hopefully JDBC drivers will be updated someday to directly handle the java.time types. Until then, we must convert into a java.sql type when transferring data to/from a database. The old java.sql classes have new methods to facilitate these conversions.

#### `java.sql.Timestamp`

For a date-time value like `Instant`, we need the [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class and its [`from( Instant )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-) method.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( now );
```

Avoid working in `java.sql.Timestamp` as it is part of the old poorly-designed mess that is the early Java date-time classes. Use them only for database transfer, then shift into java.time immediately.

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

So simple, no time zones or offset-from-UTC involved. The `Instant`, `java.sql.Timestamp`, and database storage are **all in UTC**.

### `ZonedDateTime`

When you do need to shift into some locality’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time), apply a time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" );  // Or "America/New_York" and so on.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh? Date doesn't have time zones so, this is probably why it's failing. Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
Date.from(java.time.ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant());
```

Comment: In my second line, this is what i am doing. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If your database allows you to store the timestamp along with the timezone, you should go ahead and save it as a timestamp.

If not, I would recommend that you store the date-time as per your timezone (or GMT). Add an additional column in the table to hold the value of the user's timezone.

When you fetch the value from the database, you can convert it to the user's timezone. Avoid storing just the date.